# URL based breadcrumbs display

Tags: drupal-6

Is it possible to show breadcrumbs based on the URL. For example if the user hits `example.com` it means `home->test1->test` and if user hits `example1.com` it means `home->test2->test`. Is it possible to control the breadcrumbs visibility. Any one guide me how to do this.

Comment: You have 9 questions and no accepted answers. Please review them and if an answer solved your problem, accept it.

Comment: Any suggestion to get this things work.

Comment: What theme are you using? Short answer: yes, you can achieved all the things mentioned. Long answer: depends on the theme you're using how easy is to set up. If by any change you're sub-theming Zen you're in luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very nice implementation of A very customizable breadcrumb can be found in the [**Zen**](http://drupal.org/project/zen) theme. If you already use a sub-theme of Zen then you're in luck. You;ll only probably have to configure it and you're good to go.

1. Options for the breadcrumb: each theme has it's own settings. So you'll need to add the options you'll want for youre breadcrumb (On/Off, separator, home link On/Off etc.) in a `themes/your_theme_name/theme-settings.php` file. [Here](http://drupal.org/node/177868) you'll find a starting point. For inspiration check out the `theme-settings.php` (for defining the options) and `zen.info` file (for providing the default values for the options).
2. Theme the breadcrumb: then you'll have to implement `your_theme_name_breadcrumb` function in `template.php`. Again look in the file with the same name in the Zen theme for an example.
3. Showing the breadcrumb: last step is to make sure that your breadcrumb is visible and you do this by printing the `$breadcrumb` variable. Look in the [`page.tpl.php file`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/6/source) template for the default implementation and customize it as you like.

Some other points of interests:

- [Custom breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) haven't tried it personally but sounds promising if you're looking for customizable breadcrumb trails for node types.
- An [article](http://drupal.org/node/228955) on the above mentioned Drupal module
- for those who like to get their hands dirty here you can find some nice info: http://drupal.org/node/64067

And don't forget to clear the theme cache at the end :)